# Relationship between Sharding and GridFS in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, sharding, gridfs

I was reading the MongoDB [documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/?_ga=1.90248474.1499260404.1412116785), it lists `Sharding` and `GridFS` as its two key features. 
I am wondering what the relationship between these two concept?

Comment: Relationship in what way? Sharding is about distributing data across nodes in order to improve performance on read/write operations or other localization. GridFS is not a feature but a "driver spec". It allows the storage of documents exceeding the 16MB BSON limit with a way to read and write that content as if it were a file. A detailed explaination of these "two questions" is really a bit beyond the scope of question and answer for this site.

Comment: @NeilLunn I saw some article writes that the GridFS also uses sharding, that's when it confuses me...

Comment: If you read the documentation fully, GridFS is just normal documents stored in a normal collection ( or two, one for the document meta data and one for the "chunks" of actual data ). So just like any normal collection, yes it "can" be sharded. But there is no direct relation. The documentation is fairly concise. Worth giving a read and then asking specific questions about parts you may not understand.

Comment: `GridFS` simply split file into small pieces to make sure they are less than 16MB BSON limitation. So a file maybe split to several documents. When the collection grows, you may want to distribute them into different servers. That's where `Sharding` works.